# d3heatmap() after leaflet() in R Markdown causes addLegend() to disappear

Tags: r, rstudio, htmlwidgets

I am working on an R Markdown document (`*.Rmd`) in RStudio with HTML widgets.  I have a map created by functions in the **leaflet** package, including a legend created by the `addLegend()` function.  This is then followed by a heatmap created by the `d3heatmap()` function of the **d3heatmap** package.  When I run the code using Run All Chunks, the output that appears in the Viewer pane looks fine.  When I run the code using Knit HTML, the output that appears in the pop up window is missing the legend.

What do I need to do in order to keep the legend displayed on the map, even when I display a heatmap afterwards?

Below is an example that you can try for yourself.  It's based on http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/legends.html and requires you to download the countries.geojson data from http://data.okfn.org/data/datasets/geo-boundaries-world-110m.

Using Knit HTML on this example, **if I include the heatmap**, using `{r, eval=TRUE}`, **there is no legend** on the leaflet map.  *If I exclude the heatmap*, using `{r, eval=FALSE}`, *there is a legend* on the leaflet map.

I am using R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10), Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit), Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1, with RStudio
Version 0.99.491 and packages d3heatmap_0.6.1, rgdal_1.1-3, sp_1.2-1, and leaflet_1.0.0.

````
---
title: "Testing"
output:
  html_document: default
---

Some text.

```{r, message=FALSE}
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)

countries <- readOGR("json/countries.geojson", "OGRGeoJSON",
  verbose=FALSE)

map <- leaflet(countries) %>% addTiles()
pal <- colorNumeric(
  palette = "YlGnBu",
  domain = countries$gdp_md_est)
map %>%
  addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 1,
    color = ~pal(gdp_md_est)) %>%
  addLegend("bottomright", pal = pal, values = ~gdp_md_est,
    title = "Est. GDP (2010)",
    labFormat = labelFormat(prefix = "$"),
    opacity = 1)
```

Some text.

```{r, eval=TRUE}
library(d3heatmap)
d3heatmap(mtcars)
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both leaflet and d3heatmap share the same CSS class called .info
When I uncheck the css options for .info, then you can again see the legend.

You have to manually re-assign the CSS class using the className parameter such as the following:
`addLegend("bottomright", className = "legendbox", pal = pal, values = ~gdp_md_est,`

You will have to append additional CSS settings for the new class.

[image: web capture]

Comment: This worked!  When I added the argument `className="legendbox"` to the `addLegend()` function, and ran knit HTML, the legend (re-)appeared.